# Calculate number of markers in visible area of Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have, for example, 10 markers on Google Map. But I zoomed and in visible area left only 2 markers.

Can Google Maps API somehow return me a number of markers in visible area (2 for my example)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can evaluate `map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())` with each marker to see which ones are included in the current viewport.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is not working. There is no method as such getBounds(). Below is the updated code :

```
VisibleRegion visibleRegion = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
LatLngBounds mapBound = visibleRegion.latLngBounds;
if(mapBound.contains(marker.getPosition()){
  // do somethings i.e. such as changing marker icon and others.
}
```